# Backbone.js pushstate, googlebot, serverside

Tags: javascript, seo, backbone.js, pushstate

I have a problem with Backbone Router and pushState.

Here's my router: https://gist.github.com/1672111

Well, I have couple of views, models, collections, routers with pushState, it works like charm.

If user goes to `/item` ( or even to root (`/`)), Nodejs will render the whole page ( we don't know, user has javascript enabled or googlebot comes to scrape the page ).

But if user has javascript enabled, then Backbone route will be triggered and the page will be rerendered from an ajax call. I know it's (the ajax call) necessary, but what should i do?

1. In view should i call `$( this.el ).hide()` to hide the rerendering?
2. On the server side shouldn't I render the main content just the layout? In this case I have to give different content for googlebot and just the layout for ordinary users? (IMHO not the best solution)

Finally, I have to bind the render method to the model change event, because ie8 users don't have pushstate so they are using hash based navigation, which isn't sent to the server side.

thanks

FYI: this is crosspost from backbonejs mailing list: https://groups.google.com/group/backbonejs/browse_thread/thread/17c708f4429dcd73